# Finding date difference to calculate number of days

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used a jquery ui datepicker in my hotel management system which I have been making in asp.net with C#. I want to know how to extract those checkout and checkout dates so that they could be in date format and then how to calculate the difference between them in order to calculate number of days.

Comment: Are you having issues at the client (in javascript) or at the server (in C#)

Comment: Actually when I copied this jquery datepicker in my code then it has texboxes like this  <input type="text" id="datepicker" /> now I dont know how to pick dates from this in asp.net with c# and after that how to calculate their difference.

Comment: How are you posting the values back to the server?

Comment: Erno de Weerd Those values are taken from the datepicker. I want to know how to retrieve the dates from a non asp control like this  <input type="text" id="datepicker" /> on server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberOfDays = (dateEnd - dateStart).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for that

```
DateTime start = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
DateTime finish = datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
TimeSpan difference = finish.Subtract(start);
var NumberOfDays = difference.TotalDays.ToString();
```

For finding a value try like that

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />

and in the code behind (C#):

Request.Form["datepicker"]
```

Comment: Rahul when I copied this jquery datepicker in my code then it has texboxes like this <input type="text" id="datepicker" /> now I dont know how to pick dates from this in asp.net with c# and after that how to calculate their difference. The thing that you have given is in the case when the date picker is taken from asp.net toolbox itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method for this

```
public static double DaysFrom(this DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        return (toDate - fromDate).TotalDays;
    }
```

and call it like

```
fromDate.DaysFrom(toDate);
```